# Parsing Xml response from third party web service

Tags: xml, post, https, ruby-on-rails-2, curb

I have installed cURB library for my rails 2 application and I am able to send multiple xml files to a single url of a web service as a post request. In addition to that I receive an receipt from the web service in an xml file which I need to be parsed by my application and out put the errors that have been created from the submitted file. 
Please could some one guide me with a good library and tutorial in capturing the response and parsing the xml document.

All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have already doing so, I recommend you use the libxml2 library for processing XML.  The libxml2 library is available as a package on every major Linux distribution.

```
gem install libxml-ruby
```

What follows is a standalone example, that works with Rails 2.3.14, showing how to parse results from curb objects using an XML parser.  It then demonstrates how to use XPath queries to select elements from the parsed XML document.

```
require 'xml/libxml'
require 'curb'

# I have included this part so that this serves as a standalone example

ce = Curl::Easy.new("http://www.myexperiment.org/announcements.xml")
ce.perform

# This is the part that deals with parsing the XML result

doc = LibXML::XML::Parser.string(ce.body_str).parse

# You can then use XPath queries to process the results, e.g.:

doc.find("/announcements/announcement").each do |el|
  puts el.content
end
```

Complete documentation for [libxml-ruby](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html) is available.

Comment: Thanks Don for the reply, But I wanted to retrieve an xml file from the web service after i had sent them some xml files. 
for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195314/collect-xml-response-by-third-party-web-service

Could this be used for the same case..? Thanks for the response

Comment: Yes, this can be used for that case.  The variable "request_test" in your other question is the same object as "ce" in my example.

Comment: I adjusted the example and responded to your other question using the nokogiri gem instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Don. I will install and make libXML get going right away.